# GNU R, VennDiagram, and making a complement diagram

Tags: r, venn-diagram, statistics

I have been working on Venn Diagrams in GNU R. I have tried using the packages venneuler and VennDiagram. I find that VennDiagram has a lot more granular control, but it seems to lack the documentation to fill in all the details. The closest I can find is this PPT file.
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3041657/bin/1471-2105-12-35-S4.PPT which I found from the URL: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3041657/

Here are my issues with using VennDiagram.

For the code

```
require(VennDiagram)
venn.diagram(list(B = 1:2000, A = 200:400),fill = c("yellow", "blue"), 
alpha = c(0.8, 0.8), cex =1.5, cat.pos=0, cat.fontface = 4,
lty = 1, fontfamily =3, filename = "test001.jpeg");
```

(I had an image here, but since I am new I do not have rights to post the image. Please generate the image from the code above.)

I can make a subset (hence a circle within a circle). But I am not finding a way to do the following:

1. Make BC to show as the equal of B^C. No, a literal "B^C" does not work. I would think there is a way to relabel the sets in a different property, but I have not seen a way to do it.
2. To position the labels of B^C and A^C within the sets and not on the outside as currently shown. I tried cat.pos="inner" but that way not a valid property. I also tried cat.pos=c(0,0) in the hope that I could feed it as an X,Y where X & Y are from the center of the circle, but it did not produce any different results.

---

Thanks to DWin, here is the code to complete my diagram to the exercise.
Suppose that A ⊂ B. Show that B<sup>c</sup> ⊂ A<sup>c</sup>.

```
require(VennDiagram)
plot.new()
venn.plot <- venn.diagram(
x = list(B = 1:200, A = 20:40), category.names= expression(B, A), 
          fill = c("yellow", "blue"), alpha = c(0.8, 0.8), cex =1.5, 
          cat.pos=0, cat.dist=c(-.1, -.1),  filename = NULL) ;
grid.draw(venn.plot); # grid graphic requires explicit print or draw operation
grid.text(expression(B^c),x=0.2,y=0.95)
grid.text(expression(A^c),x=0.16,y=0.95)
grid.text(expression(A^c),x=0.16,y=0.75)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
 venn.diagram(list(B = 1:200, A = 20:40), category.names= expression(B^c, A), 
            fill = c("yellow", "blue"), alpha = c(0.8, 0.8), cex =1.5, cat.pos=0, 
            cat.dist=c(.1, -.1), cat.fontface = 4,lty = 1, fontfamily =3,
            filename = "test001.jpeg")
```

To get the labels inside the circles,  supply 'cat.dist' with negative values. The trick is that the reference point is radial distance from the boundary at 12 o'clock rather than from the center. The documentation says that  the category.names argument is interpreted with plotmath syntax. The superscript operation in plotmath is done with the "^" operator. I have here moved the A" inside while leaving the B^c outside to suggest that it is the area outside the B circle that is being labeled. (I also improved the plotting time by making the example smaller.) I tried drawing three labels but that does not seem to "part of the package".

[image]

Here's a way you can annotate with `grid.text()` on the screen device:

```
plot.new()
venn.plot <- venn.diagram(
 x = list(B = 1:200, A = 20:40), category.names= expression(B^c, A), 
          fill = c("yellow", "blue"), alpha = c(0.8, 0.8), cex =1.5, 
          cat.pos=0, cat.dist=c(.05, -.1),  filename = NULL) ;
 grid.draw(venn.plot); # grid graphic requires explicit print or draw operation
 grid.text("B",x=0.8)
# then you can save to file
```

Comment: >Your notation B^C is unknown to me.

It's meant to be an exponent. So if I was to express seven squared, I would use 7^2. You can use this type of notation in MathML or in Wolfram Alpha, etc. In this case I want B to show "c" as an exponent to express that this is a compliment to B.

Comment: >To get the labels inside the circles supply 'cat.dist' with negative values. The trick is that the reference point is radial distance from the boundary rather than from the center.

When I originally added cat.pos=0, that centered the labels with respect to the horizontal position of the label. I just added the "cat.dist" so now this spinet look like "cat.pos=0, cat.dist=-500," but when I render a new diagram, it does not change the vertical alignment to inside the circle. It does not appear to move at all.

Comment: The "^"operator as a power function is obvious but completely tangential to set theory. I did in fact wonder if you were talking about the power-set, but it is now clear you were not. Its use to refer to a set complement (note the correct spelling) is not in the least bit similar, IMO. Which set elements are being "removed" or excluded with this notation?

Comment: ok, I was not sure how to express the notation I see in the book of B where c is an exponent, hence I gave it my closest shot. Is there a better way to express it on this forum and (more on topic) is there a way to express B where C is an exponent is shown as an exponent for a complement within the VennDiagram package ?

Comment: Are you trying to use B^c to indicate a superscript "c"? That seems less standard than the usual notation of B' for the complement of B but It would be possible, I suppose. It would be better to use uppercase letters for sets and lower case letters for operations or superscripts IMO.

Comment: >Are you trying to use B^c to indicate a superscript "c"? 

Yes. I understand your point given I have one stats text book that shows B' and the main MIT book that shows B^c. Given I am trying to follow the MIT book, I am trying to use the characters as per the book.

Comment: >Perhaps something like this:

Yes, both the superscript where we have B^c and the ability to move A inside the circle are exactly what I was looking for. Awesome. Thank you.

To prevent future questions on this package, what is the best resource for this package ? I tried using "help(VennDiagram)" but the info was minimal.

Comment: I used a lot of guesswork and experimentation. Basically just used the help page. So when's I my checkmark going to show up?